# Reactive objects and rwunderground functions in R

Tags: dataframe, shiny-server, rwunderground

I am using Shiny R, but I do not know to solve a problem in server. The "climate2" and "weather10" objects were not found. Likely, the "latlong" and "comp" objects show problems, but I do not know. The "latlong" argument of "forecast10day" function does not work with my "latlong" object and the "semi_join" function does not work with my "comp" object. I am copying only a part of the code because it is very long.

Many thanks!

Global R.

```
# Climate
climate <- cbind(tmin,tmax[,-c(1:3)],rhpm[,-c(1:3)],rham[,-c(1:3)])
names(climate) <- c("Long","Lat","Month","Tmin","Tmax","RHmin","RHmax")
head(climate,2)
```

Server:

```
latlong <- reactive({ 

  latlong <- as.character(c(input$Lat,input$Long))
  weather.10 <- forecast10day(set_location(lat_long = paste(latlong,collapse = ",")))
  names(weather.10)[names(weather.10) == "temp_high"] <- "Tmax"
  names(weather.10)[names(weather.10) == "temp_low"] <- "Tmin"
  weather.10$Tmax <- fahrenheit.to.celsius(weather.10$Tmax, round = 0)
  weather.10$Tmin <- fahrenheit.to.celsius(weather.10$Tmin, round = 0)

  })

  #Outputs 

  output$text0 <- renderText({
      if(input$Irrigation =="No")
        if(round(mean(min(weather.10$Tmin))) > 17 && round(mean(max(weather.10$Tmax))) < 35 && round(mean(min(weather.10$ave_humidity))) > 34 && round(mean(max(weather.10$ave_humidity))) < 87)        
        {
        paste("The combination Biological and Chemical control is recomended in Drought or Rainy period.")

      }else{

        paste("Biological or chemical control or both may be inefficient and there are low risk of epidemics")
      } 
  })

comp <- reactive ({


    #Selecting options of user
    comp <- data.frame(input$Long, input$Lat,input$Month)
    climate <- semi_join(climate, comp, by=c("Long","Lat","Month"))
    climate2 <- data.frame(unique(climate$Long),unique(climate$Lat),unique(climate$Month),round(mean(climate$Tmin)),
                           round(mean(climate$Tmax)),round(mean(climate$RHmin)),
                           round(mean(climate$RHmax)))
    names(climate2) <- c("Long", "Lat","Mont","Tmin","Tmax","RHmin","RHmax")  
  })

output$text1 <- renderText({

    if(input$Irrigation =="50-60%")
      if(climate2$Tmax > 17 && climate2$Tmin < 35 && climate2$RHmin > 34 && climate2$RHmax < 87)
      {
        paste("The combination Biological and Chemical control is recomended.")

      }else{

        paste("Biological or chemical control or both may be inefficient. You can see more information in FORECASTING.")
      }

  })
```

This is my UI.

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
                h3("Information system to control Dry Root Rot in Common Beans"),
                  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                  numericInput("Long", label = h3("Longitude:"), value = -49),
                  numericInput("Lat", label = h3("Latitude:"), value = -17),
                  actionButton("recalc", "Show point"),

                    selectInput(inputId = "Irrigation",label = "Irrigation (Soil Available Water)", 
                                choices = c("No","50-60%","80-90%","110-120%","140-150%"),
                                selected = "80-90%"
                    ),
                    selectInput(inputId = "Month", label = "Current Month", choices = c("Jan","Feb","March","April","May","June","July",
                                                                                        "Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")),
```

Comment: If you want to use variables across different reactive functions u have To define them As a reactivevalue or a reactive function. Reactive function have To be called like functionName()